# ionic send http.post and php receive a GET request

Tags: php, ionic3, ionic4

I already developed ionic 4 in my Mac. When trying to improve an app in ionic 3, my `http.post` (angular) calls in php is received as `GET ($ _SERVER ['REQUEST_METHOD'])`. I discovered that my parameters are not being recognized in php.
* I read the other posts and none solved my problem
Thank you!

```
import { Http , Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

let parametros = JSON.stringify({
  idtApostador: localStorage.getItem("idtApostador"),
});
let headers = new Headers(
  {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
  });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.post(url, parametros, options)
  .timeout(15000)
  .subscribe(data => {
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I ask, I answer. :)
https instead of http.

Comment: In the url the only change I made was to call it with https.

Answer (score 0):

Use

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

Instead of HTTP